# When does intersection commute with module multiplication?

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ and $M$ an $R$-module. When do we have the equality:

> $\bigcap_{n \ge 1} (I^nM) = (\bigcap_{n \ge 1} I^n) M$

I was hoping "always" would be the answer, but this seems too good to be true, and I'm not quite sure how to prove it. I can certainly see some special cases where it's true, but I'm trying to find the most general conditions, maybe some constraint on $R$ if necessary.

Comment: This can be false when $M$ is an ideal of $R$. Consider $R=F[x,y]/\langle xy,y^2\rangle$, $I=R(x+1)$ and $M=Ry$.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I made a mistake in thinking the ideal $M$ would be the same as $I$. Do you know some conditions when the above equality may be true? Perhaps when $R$ is a domain?

Answer (score 1):

Even for relatively "nice" $R$ and $M$, this equality can fail.  For example, if $R = \mathbb{Z}$, $I = (m)$, $M = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers, the left side is all of $M$, while the right side is 0.

Some cases where equality holds:  Assume $R$ is Noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated.  Then by Krull's Intersection Theorem (see e.g. Eisenbud, Corollary 5.4), there exists an $r \in I$ such that $(1-r)(\bigcap_{n \ge 1}(I^nM)) = 0$.  Now if $M$ is torsion-free, or if $R$ is a local ring and $I$ is the maximal ideal (which forces $1-r$ to be invertible) then $\bigcap_{n \ge 1}(I^nM) = 0$ and hence both sides are 0 (since the right side is clearly contained in the left).